# how to change structure of multiple tables at once in sql

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables in my database with different names but all have the same structure. Is there a way that I can change the structure to add a column to every table?

Comment: I don't think this can be accomplished without looping over the tables. What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Faber suggested, you can accomplish this only in a loop.

I have provided the code sample below to accomplish this.

```
    private static final String ALTER_USER_TABLE_ColumnDetails = 
        " ADD NEW_COLUMN_NAME TEXT";

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
 // strTableList - Array of Table Names
       for(int i=0;i<strTableList.length;i++)
       {
       db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "+strTableList[i]+ALTER_USER_TABLE_ColumnDetails);
       }
    }
```

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL inhericance.**

(works in postgresql atleast)
if all the tables inherit a base table, adding a column to the base table would add it to all the others. (after aquiring a lock on every table in the database)

If your DBMs doesn't do this sort of sql inheritance, then i think "no":

Get a list of tables and write a looping script, (or use find and replace).

Answer (score 0):

If you were using MS SQL you could do it directly in SQL, for example:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
if not exists (select * from sys.columns
            where object_id = object_id("?")
            and name = "NewColumnName")
 begin
     ALTER TABLE ? ADD NewColumnName varchar(50) NULL;
 end
 ';
```